# How can I kill the parent shell script process without killing child process?

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

I write shell script that runs PHP process.
But it was not running in background. Can I kill the shell script without killing the PHP process which is running?

Comment: and some how duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533377/why-child-process-still-alive-after-parent-process-was-killed-in-linux

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"it was not run in background"* See also [When a parent process is killed by “kill -9”, will subprocess also be killed?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1491674/2173773)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you have to separate it first.  To separate the child from the parent process, run:

`kill -20 PID`

`kill -18 PID`

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625409/how-do-i-put-an-already-running-process-under-nohup

If you are on the same terminal with the process, type `ctrl-z` to stop the parent, and the use `ps -ef` to find the PID of the php child.  Use the kill lines above to effectively separate the child from the parent.  Then `fg` back into your shell script and it should terminate normally, or you can `kill -9` the shell script by PID or name directly while you are at the prompt.  Otherwise, killing the parent will (eventually) take out the child.